# I have many children arrays and i want all children arrays in single array in php

Tags: php

Hi i have many children arrays inside array all data exactly comes from api output result is i tried array recursive php but not worked

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            
            [price] => 100
            [weight] => 42
            [sub_option] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [price] => 25.99
                            [points] => 32
                            [sub_option] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [price] => 27.99
                                            [weight] => 83
                                            [sub_option] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [price] => 14.99
                                                            [weight] => 50
                                                            [sub_option] => NULL
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [price] => 24.99
                            [weight] => 25
                            [sub_option] => NULL

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 100
            [weight] => 4233
            [sub_option] => NULL
        )

)
```

like this but i want output like this ......

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 100
            [weight] => 42
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 25.99
            [points] => 32
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [price] => 27.99
            [weight] => 83
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [price] => 14.99
            [weight] => 50
            [sub_option] => NULL
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [price] => 24.99
            [weight] => 25
            [sub_option] => NULL

        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [price] => 100
            [weight] => 4233
            [sub_option] => NULL
        )
)
```

I am using PHP version 7 and i also tried to search many online solutions from stackoverflow but i cant find please help me thanks

I tried this code but not working

```
$output = [];

$arr1 = [];
$arr2 = [];
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    $arr1 = [
        'price' => $value['price'],
        'weight' => $value['weight'],

    ];

    if(isset($value['sub_option']) && is_array($value['sub_option'])){
        foreach($value['sub_option'] as $val2){
            $arr2 = [
                'price' => $val2['price'],
                'weight' => $val2['weight'],
            ];

        }
    }

$output[] = $arr1+$arr2;

}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain the specific problem - that's how Stackoverflow operates...don't expect us to research and code it all again for you from the beginning - it's possible you're already quite close to a working solution, so it would be a waste of time potentially. See also [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue. As you're new, please also take the [tour]. You can [edit] your post when you're ready. Thanks.

Comment: My question is simple i want all child arrays in only one array

Comment: The question might be simple but that doesn't mean the solution is. That's why you should show what you've done already, then we can save time by either fixing it or ruling it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method to doing this (with anonymous function)

```
#example date
$data = [
    [
        'price' => 101,
        'weight' => 42,
        'sub_option' =>
            [
                'price' => 101,
                'weight' => 43,
                'sub_option' => [
                                 [
                                  'price' => 101,
                                  'weight' => 44,
                                  'sub_option' => null
                                 ]
                                ]
            ]
    ],
    [
        'price' => 102,
        'weight' => 42,
        'sub_option' => null
    ]
];
#global collector
$result = [];
#function variable, here with null value so we can use it as reference
$func = null;
#create the real function & use references
$func = function ($current) use (&$result, &$func) {
    #look for assoc array key
    if (isset($current['price'])) {
        #copy and unset not needed keys
        $tmp = $current;
        unset($tmp['sub_option']);
        #collect 
        $result[] = $tmp;
        #check for subarray and go deeper
        if (is_array($current['sub_option'])) {
            $func($current['sub_option']);
        }
    } elseif (is_array($current)) {
        #iterate index arrays
        foreach ($current as $sub) {
            $func($sub);
        }
    }
};
$func($data);
var_export($result);
```

I will not explain this in detail, because first answer from **GrumpyCrouton** should be taken/accepted. But when you take some time, may you learn new stuff and how php works from this little code snipped.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method of doing this

```
function format_array($arr) {
    $tmp = [];
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        //pass each of the root values to the helper function
        //also pass a reference to $tmp
        format_array_helper($a, $tmp);
    }
    return $tmp;
}

function format_array_helper($loop_value, &$tmp) {
    
    //set the sub options to it's own variable,
    //unset the sub options from the main variable
    $sub_options = $loop_value['sub_option'];
    unset($loop_value['sub_option']);
    
    //add the main variable to $tmp
    $tmp[] = $loop_value;
    
    //if there are sub options
    if(!empty($sub_options)) {
        foreach($sub_options as $sub) {
            
            //pass each root of sub_options to the helper function
            //also pass the reference to tmp
            format_array_helper($sub, $tmp);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Let's assume your array is called `$arr`. Here is the output of `print_r(format_array($arr));`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 100
            [weight] => 42
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 25.99
            [weight] => 32
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [price] => 27.99
            [weight] => 83
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [price] => 14.99
            [weight] => 50
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [price] => 24.99
            [weight] => 25
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [price] => 100
            [weight] => 4233
        )

)
```